# How to create optimal solution for this conflict problem?

Tags: algorithm, logic, greedy

Assume you are defending a beach from battleships of various length with rail guns that will destroy anything in a straight line. The battleships are on a x,y grid and have parameters (x1,x2,y) for the 2 sides and y coordinate. You only have limited resources and need to try sink all battleships with least amount of rail guns which will be placed on the x coordinates.

[image: For example grid might look like this]

A battleship is destroyed if x1 <= x <= x2 and all battleships have height of 1.

Currently the solution I have is to add rail guns at position that sink most ships then remove those ships from list and then look for the next position that will sink the most ships in the updated list and so on until there is no ships left. However I've found a counter example to it.

I'm at lost at what other optimal solutions are available.

Comment: In which case it will not work?

Comment: https://imgur.com/gMj2wjf , in this scenario if you place railguns at the most conflicts and remove ships from list then repeat you end up with 4 railguns at (2,7,1,4) where is you could do it with 3 guns at (1,3,7)

Comment: In your example 5 railgun needed (0,1,2,3,7). If they shoot vertically right?

Comment: Does shoot makes wildfire for all board-connected ships (like wooden ones)? Seem you have to show exact problem formulation.

Comment: they just have to touch the ship so putting in my first example placing gun at 1 will destroy 3 ships.

Comment: 3 ships? So shooting is along line dividing cells 0 and 1, not  in the cell middle? In this case my approach is suitable with minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your tags include `greedy`. Greedy approach might look like this:

Sort start and finish x-coordinates together with corresponding ship indexes.

Walk through finish list. If current item index is marked - ignore it, otherwise mark indexes for all start items upto current coordinate, and fire at current coordinate.

For given example you will fire at 3, 6, and 8

Three lists/arrays. One contains pairs `(start[i]; i)`, another  - pairs `(end[i]; i)`, the third - `boolean[N]` for marks.

The first item in end-list is 3 for ship (0,3,1). So we fire and kill (mark) ships (0,3,1), (1,4,0) and (1,4,4), because their starts are less than 3.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand, so to clarify I sort the ships by the order of right hand side index and place rail gun at the first right index and remove ships from list as I go along right? This was what I thought but was thinking it surely couldnt be this simple but I also couldnt come up with any counters.

Comment: In general - yes. I added short description in the answer.

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand killing condition well - I consider that gun kills all ships at it's vertical line

Comment: How would you go about proving this?